# Debugging the code in Eclipse. Internal loop case

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

While debugging the code in Eclipse, I runned into the following problem. There is a WHILE Loop with possibly ~10,000 iterations. Therefore, it's not a good idea to use Step here. So, I placed the Breakpoint right after this WHILE Loop. But it seems that this WHILE Loop runned into the internal loop. I don't know how to find the right iteration that caused this problem. Is there any way to differentiate between the long execution time of the code and the internal loop? What should I do to quickly find such deadlock places in the code?

P.S. The code worked fine with small datasets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Code rewriting for testing***
Isn't it more likely that it is exponentially slowing down, like searching in a growing LinkedList, allocations, transactions.

```
if (i > 8000) {
    show loop duration; // breakpoint here
} else if (i > 6000) {
    show loop duration; // breakpoint here
} else if (i > 4000) {
    show loop duration; // breakpoint here
}
```

So I would introduce **StopWatch** if the loops are getting slower. Using **findBugs** to check on handle leakage. And finally rewrite in smaller methods helps for legacy code.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a deadlock, you can run the program in debug without a break point and wait for it to deadlock and then stop it.

If you want it to stop on a particular iteration you can add a conditional break point, but this can make execution slower.

What I do is add the condition to the code, something like

```
if (i == 10000 && condition)
    Thread.yield(); // add break point here.
```

or if you have a method which returns a bad value you can do something like

```
boolean ok = method();
if (!ok)
   method(); // add a break point here so you can see why it fails.
```

Comment: You don't actually need to put the conditions in your code. You cam specify them for the breakpoint directly via Breakpoint Properties.

Comment: This why I suggested it first.  For a long running loop this can be pretty slow.  Adding the condition has almost no overhead.